# ASP.NET MVC how to always visit the Index Page/Action and how to set the default route.

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

Assuming in my project I have such a structure:

```
public class SalesOrderController : OrderController
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

    }
}
```

---

```
public class PurchaseOrderController : OrderController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

    }
}
```

---

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

    }

}
```

Normally, you visit the web pages like this:

myUrl/SalesOrder/Index

myUrl/PurchaseOrder/Index

myUrl/Home/Index

How do I make it such that when I visit myUrl/SalesOrder it will automatically visit the index page of that controller? How do I make this apply for all controllers? Is it through routing? Or there is another method?

EDIT:

I have modified the default route because I struggled with configuring the first page to visit when visit 'myUrl' in the address page.

my default route currently looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

I tried controlling the first page the web app should visit by changing web.config with markup like this:

```
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <add value="Login/Login" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

I also tried changing the default document on IIS but I can't seem to configure the first page the web app should visit.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It will already do that by default if you have the not removed or altered the Default route

Comment: Is it not working with the default route configuration ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have edited the question with more details. I altered the default route.

Comment: Why have you done that? (having a Login method as the default makes no sense - you apply the `[Authorize]` attribute to controllers/methods so that a user is automatically redirected to to Login method

Answer (score 2):

You can use attribute routing to achieve this something like this

```
public class PurchaseOrderController : OrderController
{
    [Route("PurchaseOrder")]
    [Route("PurchaseOrder/Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("Home")]
    [Route("Home/Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

    }

}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1).